# IIS 8 CS0016: Could not write to output file 'The directory name is invalid'

Tags: iis

I have been trying to get three MVC apps running under my local IIS. The first one builds fine but the other two fails with the above error. All three uses ApplicationPoolIdentity as the identity

Using sysinternal's process monitor, it seems the other 2 apps are trying to access the temp directory of the first one, ie. C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp where %userprofile% is the name of the first application pool.

I have tried to delete all three profiles from c:\Users and registry keys at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

It seems like the solution is to fix the environment variable %userprofile% for the other 2 apps so that they each point to their own respective temp directories but how do you do this?

Or is there something else I'm missing....

I'm running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to set the TEMP and TMP evnironment system variables to point c:\Temp and c:\tmp respectively (note I'm not using %USERPROFILE%). Then I blew the security away on them.

What a brute - but hey it worked.